# Dynamically filling text inputs

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile

I'm generating a interface dinamically and when I put a text-input I show next to it a button with a popup and a listview inside with some choices. This way the user could enter his own text or select it from the popup.

Well, the problem is that when I generate the interface I use an ID+number for each pair of textfield+popupbutton so, for example, I have:

```
 #Text-input1 and popup with id=1.
```

What I'm trying to do is: When I select one choice of my list I fill the associated text-input with the value of the choice. In my list I have something like this:

```
  <li><a onclick="fillText('+myid+','+"'myvalue'"+')"</a>Myvalue1</li>
```

And my function has to do this:

```
 $('#text-input1').val('myvalue')
```

So I have tried with this:

```
    function fillText(id, text){
       document.execCommand("$('#text-input"+id+"').val('"+text+"')");
    }
```

But it's not working. I'm sure that it is a clean way to do it, maybe using the document on click function in jQuery, but I can't see it yet.
I have tested to put directly $('#text-input1').val('myvalue'); inside of my function and its works.

Comment: id and text pass correct in `fillText` function?

Comment: Yes, I just check it..

Comment: Where `x` is declared?

Comment: Can you please create jsfiddle?

Comment: could you post a jsfiddle mockup of your issue, as currently there is a few issues with the code you've posted, which make it hard to separate the issue from quickly typed code.

Comment: I can't copy exactly the code because it is generated dinamically, but hope it helps: http://jsfiddle.net/vjLKB/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

**js**

```
function fillText(id, text){
   document.execCommand($("#text-basic"+id).val(text));
}
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vjLKB/3/)

You have some errors in your js function. I fixed them.